# How can I create a dataframe based on conditions of two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have three dataframes (see below). I would like to use information from DF1 and DF2 to populate DF3 based on some conditions. I have set out DF3 so those conditions can be seen.

In the example figures I show, the value corrasponding to Jan-23, January, 2023 for Geothermal is derived from looking at the % in DF1 for Geothermal, then multiplying it by the value corrasponding to 2023 for Geothermal in DF2 and then multiplying that by 730. So 70% * 284.1 * 730 which gives the answer.

I only did some examples in my dataset as didn't want to long of a chart in the post but the idea is that DF3 has dates going out to 2030 so I want to be able to automate the whole processes for a lot more technologies and dates etc.

Also I created an example for DF3, and happy to do this manually but if anyone knows how to do this manually so it pivots the index technologies across the top and adds the date/year columns, that would be helpful but not essential to the question.

I have no idea how to attempt this in either python or excel so open to any suggestions. Thank you.

DF1

| Month | January | February | March | April | May | June | July | August | Sept | October | November | December |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Geothermal | 70% | 74% | 73% | 71% | 71% | 70% | 72% | 72% | 73% | 67% | 70% | 75% |
| Hydroelectric | 42% | 43% | 43% | 45% | 50% | 48% | 42% | 37% | 32% | 31% | 36% | 38% |
| Nuclear | 100% | 96% | 89% | 82% | 89% | 96% | 97% | 97% | 93% | 83% | 91% | 99% |
| Other Gas | 67% | 65% | 62% | 60% | 62% | 64% | 65% | 66% | 66% | 63% | 64% | 66% |
| Wind | 35% | 37% | 39% | 41% | 36% | 34% | 26% | 27% | 31% | 36% | 37% | 37% |
| Combined Cycle | 53% | 53% | 49% | 46% | 48% | 59% | 69% | 69% | 60% | 52% | 49% | 53% |
| Gas Turbine | 10% | 10% | 10% | 10% | 10% | 12% | 15% | 15% | 12% | 11% | 10% | 10% |
| Steam Turbine | 8% | 8% | 9% | 10% | 12% | 17% | 23% | 22% | 16% | 13% | 9% | 8% |
| Internal Combustion | 13% | 13% | 13% | 13% | 12% | 15% | 19% | 19% | 16% | 15% | 14% | 14% |

DF2

| Technology | 2023 | 2024 | 2025 | 2026 | 2027 | 2028 | 2029 | 2030 |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hydroelectric | 3745.6 | 3745.6 | 3745.6 | 3745.6 | 3745.6 | 3745.6 | 3745.6 | 3745.6 |  |  |  |  |
| Geothermal | 284.1 | 284.1 | 284.1 | 284.1 | 284.1 | 284.1 | 284.1 | 284.1 |  |  |  |  |
| Other Gas | 59.6 | 59.6 | 59.6 | 59.6 | 59.6 | 59.6 | 59.6 | 59.6 |  |  |  |  |
| Combined Cycle | 23047.1 | 23047.1 | 23047.1 | 23047.1 | 23047.1 | 23047.1 | 23047.1 | 23047.1 |  |  |  |  |
| Gas Turbine | 12607.6 | 12559.3 | 12613.3 | 12613.3 | 12613.3 | 12613.3 | 12613.3 | 12613.3 |  |  |  |  |
| Internal Combustion | 401.5 | 401.5 | 393.8 | 401.5 | 401.5 | 401.5 | 401.5 | 401.5 |  |  |  |  |
| Steam Turbine | 2672.6 | 3128.1 | 4880.4 | 4880.4 | 4880.4 | 4880.4 | 4880.4 | 4880.4 |  |  |  |  |
| Nuclear | 2323 | 1201 | 1205 | 2323 | 2323 | 2323 | 2323 | 2323 |  |  |  |  |
| Wind | 6366.5 | 6285 | 6304 | 6269.5 | 6269.5 | 6269.5 | 6269.5 | 6269.5 |  |  |  |  |
| Other Gas | 262.1 | 262.1 | 262.1 | 262.1 | 262.1 | 262.1 | 262.1 | 262.1 |  |  |  |  |

DF3

| Date | Year | Month | Geothermal | Hydroelectric | Nuclear | Other Gas | Wind | Combined Cycle | Gas Turbine | Steam Turbine | Internal Combustion |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-23 | 2023 | January | 145838.758 | 1157697.539 | 1697146.63 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Feb-23 | 2023 | February | 153263.427 | 1188321.565 | 1634741.56 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Jan-24 | 2024 | January |  |  | 877431.384 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Feb-24 | 2024 | February |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Mar-24 | 2024 | March |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```
data = {'Hydroelectric': [3, 2, 1], 'Geothermal': [30,20,10]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=['Jan', 'Feb', 'March'])

data = {'Hydroelectric': [3, 2, 1], 'Geothermal': [30,20,10]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=[2023, 2024, 2025])

# Concat the two dataframes
concated_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

# Create year_month columns, multiplying accordingly
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for column_str in concated_df.columns:
    if isinstance(column_str, str):
        for column_not_str in concated_df.columns:
            if not isinstance(column_not_str, str):
                new_df["{}_{}".format(column_str, column_not_str)] = concated_df[column_not_str] * concated_df[column_str] * 730

# Transpose, split your column names and set the index
new_df = new_df.T    
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
new_df[['Month', 'Year']] = new_df['index'].str.split('_', 1, expand=True)
new_df.drop("index", axis=1, inplace=True)
new_df.set_index(["Year", "Month"], inplace=True)
```